# thymeleaf absolute URL with variable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to inject a domain url into a link using Thymeleaf. My url is being passed from the controller because i put logging and saw it.

my link is as such in my Thymeleaf html template:

```
<link type="text/css" th:href="@{${DomainUrl}/web/assets/css/foundation5/foundation.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

however, when I run it locally it doesn't replace the domain, for example, throws an error (because the URL is not found of course) render as such:
http://localhost:8081/pss/ui/$%7BDomainUrl%7D/web/assets/css/components.css

Comment: Should work just like that. Maybe `DomainUrl` view variable is not set??

Comment: I do add it as such and logged to make sure it is being populated..
mav.addObject("DomainUrl", ctx.getDomainUrl());

Comment: add `[[${DomainUrl}]]` as text node (simple text in html) to your markup, is that rendering given domain?

Comment: yes it does print it. i found out that there was a base url tag which was why it was putting in the domain, however, i removed that and when it is a link as my example:
<link type="text/css" th:href="@{${DomainUrl}/web/assets/css/foundation5/foundation.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />

still does not populated the correct domain, perhaps it is a tag in the controller that is making the links relative. any idea on what Spring bean i can look for?

Comment: so you need relative or absolute cuz im lost now? chceck thymeleaf docs on that topic as well. maybe one of # beans will help

Answer (score 7):

Ok so in order for this to work you must use preprocess operator `__expression__` to get propert link so you will end up with somethink like this

```
<link type="text/css" th:href="@{__${DomainUrl}__/web/assets/css/foundation5/foundation.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

this will preprocess and resolve `${DomainUrl}` expression, and will pass resulting string to to `@` expression processor. Tested and work like charm:

```
<a th:href="@{__${currentUrl}__/blah/blah/blahhhh}">hey there</a>
```

generates

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/admin/place/list/blah/blah/blahhhh">hey there</a>
```

where `http://localhost:8080/admin/place/list/` is `currentUrl`

in my

Comment: Should be accepted answer or at least should mention why did this answer not solve that problem (it worked for me)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution for it. I had to make the link into literal as such:

```
<link type="text/css" th:href="@{|${DomainUrl}/web/assets/css/foundation5/normalize.css|}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<link type="text/css" th:href="@{${DomainUrl + '/web/assets/css/foundation5/foundation.min.css'}}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Does `${DomainUrl}` start with `http://` or `https://`?  That makes a difference when creating a link with `@{}` expressions.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the difference

Comment: When you say "absolute url", that has a specific meaning -- that it starts with `http://` or `https://`. See the thymeleaf documentation: 
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls .  As for the link I made, you can't mix unquoted strings and variables like you did.  That's why I put  the rest of the url within `${}`.

Comment: ahh i see what you ment. I understood thet https and http makes a difference here.... alternating schemes are confusion here